# how to open usb port and receive data of it using asio library?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio

I have a device that communicates with another application(not written by me) that I want to get value of it using my application. googling I found the ansio library,I installed it and found [this](http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html) tutorial for getting started.

the question: how I to get the device name to set in port name?
using `lsusb`, I get:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ac8:305b Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. ZC0305 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I want to handle the webcam device:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ac8:305b Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. ZC0305 Webcam
```

then I wrote:

```
try {
    SimpleSerial serial("/dev/ttyUSB4",115200); // get SimpleSerial class on link above
    cout<<serial.readLine()<<endl;
    return 0;

} catch(boost::system::system_error& e)
{
    cout<<"Error: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

but it given an: `Error: open: No such file or directory`
how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running your program under `strace` and look for the string `/dev/ttyUSB4` and check the function calls around that point to get a clue of what the library is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Type `ls /dev/tty*` in the shell and choose one of the resulting ports. Unfortunately it can't be said for sure which one will be the right one. Otherwise you can try extracting the correct port by processing the output of `dmesg`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when a device is connected to a USB port, it is records a message in the kernel ring buffer.  This log will *often* give you the information you are looking for.  To find it,

1. Connect your device
2. run `dmesg` or `dmesg | tail -20` to see the last 20 lines of the buffer.

The output of the `dmesg` command should be something similar to the following.

```
.
.
.
[ 1562.334350] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1566.526225] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1566.652880] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303, bcdDevice= 4.00
[ 1566.652885] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1566.652888] usb 1-1: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
[ 1566.652891] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc. 
[ 1566.655451] pl2303 1-1:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[ 1566.656634] usb 1-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

Notes:

- The last line tells you the appropriate ttyUSB device number.  This is driver specific.  Many USB devices are not accessible via /dev/ttyUSB#.